# Delete hasManyThrough relationship rows using Laravel's Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, has-many-through

I have three models, `Advertiser`, `PtcAd`, and `PtcCampaign`. When deleting a *Advertiser* I want to delete all related *PtcAds* and *PtcCampaigns*. The *Advertiser* has many *PtcCampaigns* through *PtcAds*.

**Advertiser Model**

```
use SoftDeletes;

protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

public function ptcAds()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\PtcAd');
}

public function ptcCampaigns()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\PtcCampaign', 'App\PtcAd');
}

public function delete()
{
    $this->ptcAds()->delete();
    // I'VE TRIED WITH AND WITHOUT THIS
    $this->ptcCampaigns()->delete();

    return parent::delete();
}
```

**PtcAd Model**

```
use SoftDeletes;

protected $fillable = ['advertiser_id', 'title'];

protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

public function advertiser()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Advertiser');
}

public function ptcCampaigns()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ptcCampaign');
}

public function delete()
{
    $this->ptcCampaigns()->delete();

    return parent::delete();
}
```

**PtcCampaign Model**

```
use SoftDeletes;

public $timestamps = false;

protected $fillable = ['ptc_ad_id', 'clicks'];

protected $dates = ['paused_at', 'deleted_at'];

public function ptcAd()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\PtcAd');
}
```

**My tests:**

```
public function test_delete_advertiser()
{
    $advertiser = factory(Advertiser::class)->create();

    $ptcAd = factory(PtcAd::class)->create(['advertiser_id' => $advertiser->id]);

    $ptcCampaign = factory(PtcCampaign::class)->create(['ptc_ad_id' => $ptcAd->id]);

    $this->assertTrue($advertiser->delete());
    $this->assertFalse(Advertiser::all()->contains($advertiser));
    $this->assertFalse(PtcAd::all()->contains($ptcAd));

    // THE FOLLOWING TEST DOESN'T WORK!
    $this->assertFalse(PtcCampaign::all()->contains($ptcCampaign));
}

// ALL OF THE FOLLOWING TESTS WORK!
public function test_delete_ad()
{
    $ptcAd = factory(PtcAd::class)->create();

    $ptcCampaign = factory(PtcCampaign::class)->create(['ptc_ad_id' => $ptcAd->id]);

    $this->assertTrue($ptcAd->delete());
    $this->assertFalse(PtcAd::all()->contains($ptcAd));
    $this->assertFalse(PtcCampaign::all()->contains($ptcCampaign));
}
```

The `$this->assertFalse(PtcCampaign::all()->contains($ptcCampaign))` in the  `test_delete_advertiser()` test fails, why?

I have more tests to make sure all the relationships work so I really don't know what could possibly be wrong. My next attempt would be to make `foreach` in the Advertiser's delete() method but maybe there's something simpler and I want to understand why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks the problem is with the sequence of delete statement.

Try by changing the sequence like below:

```
public function delete()
{
    $this->ptcCampaigns()->delete();

    $this->ptcAds()->delete();

    return parent::delete();
}
```

Comment: That does it! Thank you! Now I have another related question, since the `PtcAd` model has the `delete()` method set up to delete `PtcCampaign`s in the relationship, why do I need to call `$this->ptcCampaigns()->delete();` from the `Advertiser` model? Shouldn't it chain?

Comment: When you do `$this->ptcAds()->delete()` it creates query and delete the rows so it calls the `delete` function query builder class. But if you delete  `ptcAds` using `foreach` then it calls the delete function of Model class and it will also delete the `ptcCampaigns`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Laravel's Model Events (`deleting`) to delete related models like this:

```
class Advertiser extends Eloquent
{
    public function ptcAds()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('PtcAd');
    }

    // this is a recommended way to declare event handlers
    protected static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($adv) { // before delete() method call this
             $adv->ptcAds()->delete();
             // do the rest of the cleanup...
        });
    }
}

// Same for PtcCompaigns

class PtcAd extends Eloquent
{
    public function ptcCompaigns()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('PtcCompaigns');
    }

    // this is a recommended way to declare event handlers
    protected static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($ptc_ad) { // before delete() method call this
             $ptc_ad->ptcCompaigns()->delete();
             // do the rest of the cleanup...
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!